# Condense Linq logic into one query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, intellisense

I'm passing in two parameters to a method, either an account number or and organization number. There is only one parameter that can have a value at a time. Meaning, if I pass in an account number then the Organization number is null. Vis-versa.

Currently I'm trying to sort an array of Accounts associated to either a person or organization. I take the accounts the entity is directly related to and sort that first.

```
// Accounts entity is directly involved with
mainAccounts = accounts
    .Where(acct => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? acct.PrimaryPersonNumber : acct.PrimaryOrganizationNumber) == entityNumber)
    .OrderBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
```

Then I look at a `RoleCode` variable attached to each entity to sort on that.

The problem I'm having is trying to combined these two queries into one, kind of like what I did with my first query.

```
if (persNbr.HasValue)
{
    // Accounts Person takes a role in
    secondaryAccounts = accounts
                        .Where(acct => acct.PrimaryPersonNumber != entityNumber)
                        .OrderBy(acct => acct.PersonRoles
                                             .Where(role => role.PersNbr == entityNumber)
                                             .Select(role => role.RoleOrder).Min())
                        .ThenBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
}
else
{
    // Accounts Organization takes a role in
    secondaryAccounts = accounts
                        .Where(acct => acct.PrimaryOrganizationNumber != entityNumber)
                        .OrderBy(acct => acct.OrganizationRoles
                                             .Where(role => role.OrgNbr == entityNumber)
                                             .Select(role => role.RoleOrder).Min())
                        .ThenBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
```

I tried to following, but the C# intellisense complains that the object (either `acct.PersonRoles` or `acct.OrganizationRoles`) doesn't exist, and it won't, until run time.

```
secondaryAccounts = accounts
    .Where(acct => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? acct.PrimaryPersonNumber : acct.PrimaryOrganizationNumber) != entityNumber)
    .OrderBy(acct => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? acct.PersonRoles : acct.OrganizationRoles) // <-- Intellisense can't get past this line
                     .Where(role => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? role.PersNbr : role.OrgNbr) == entityNumber)
                     .Select(role => role.RoleOrder).Min())
    .ThenBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
```

How would I do this?

This is my method if it helps out.

```
private Account[] SortAccountsOnPersonRoles(Account[] accounts, long? persNbr, long? orgNbr)
{
    IEnumerable<Account> mainAccounts;
    IEnumerable<Account> secondaryAccounts;

    long entityNumber = (long)((persNbr.HasValue) ? persNbr : orgNbr);

    // Accounts entity is directly involved with
    mainAccounts = accounts
        .Where(acct => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? acct.PrimaryPersonNumber : acct.PrimaryOrganizationNumber )== entityNumber)
        .OrderBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);

    if (persNbr.HasValue)
    {
        // Accounts Person takes a role in
        secondaryAccounts = accounts
                            .Where(acct => acct.PrimaryPersonNumber != entityNumber)
                            .OrderBy(acct => acct.PersonRoles
                                                 .Where(role => role.PersNbr == entityNumber)
                                                 .Select(role => role.RoleOrder).Min())
                            .ThenBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        // Accounts Organization takes a role in
        secondaryAccounts = accounts
                            .Where(acct => acct.PrimaryOrganizationNumber != entityNumber)
                            .OrderBy(acct => acct.OrganizationRoles
                                                 .Where(role => role.OrgNbr == entityNumber)
                                                 .Select(role => role.RoleOrder).Min())
                            .ThenBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
    }

    return mainAccounts.Concat(secondaryAccounts).ToArray();
}
```

**EDIT:** The error from Intellisense says:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between PersonRoles[] and OrganizationRoles[]

It's happening because of this statement I tried:

```
.OrderBy(acct => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? acct.PersonRoles : acct.OrganizationRoles) // <-- Intellisense can't get past this line
     .Where(role => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? role.PersNbr : role.OrgNbr) == entityNumber)
```

Intellisense cannot detemine the value of the lamda variable to perform the LINQ query `.Where()`. Specfically,

```
acct => ((acct.PrimaryPersonNumber.HasValue) ? acct.PersonRoles : acct.OrganizationRoles)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting from intellisense?

Comment: You can't return either `PersonRoles` or `OrganizationRoles` from the same LINQ expression, since they are different types.  This is further complicated by their being arrays, which means that even if the two types are part of a common type hierarchy, it won't be easy to get a consistent return type for the expression that could return one or the other under different circumstances.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach Yeah I was thinking I could use their base class, but It's going to get too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

First, create two separate functions with different parameters.

```
private Account[] SortAccountsOnPersonRolesByPersonNumber(Account[] accounts, 
    long personNbr) 

private Account[] SortAccountsOnPersonRolesByOrgNumber(Account[] accounts, 
    long orgNbr)
```

Then, change the main function so that instead of passing in parameters for both `personNbr` and `orgNbr` and figuring which have values (what if both do or neither do), you pass in functions.

I don't know what the logic is, so I've given the parameters rather meaningless names.

```
private Account[] SortAccountsOnPersonRoles(Account[] accounts, 
    Func<Account, bool> accountComparison, 
    Func<Role, bool> roleComparison)
```

Now, instead of duplicating the whole query because or two conditions are different, you can do this:

```
   secondaryAccounts = accounts
       .Where(acct => accountComparison(acct))
       .OrderBy(acct => acct.PersonRoles
       .Where(role => roleComparison(role))
           .Select(role => role.RoleOrder).Min())
       .ThenBy(acct => acct.AccountNumber);
```

Now from the two new functions, call the "inner" function and pass in those conditions as arguments.

```
private Account[] SortAccountsOnPersonRolesByPersonNumber(Account[] accounts, 
    long personNbr) 
{
    Func<Account, bool> accountComparison = acct => acct.PrimaryPersonNumber != personNbr;
    Func<Role, bool> roleComparison = role => role.PersNbr == personNbr;
    return SortAccountsOnPersonRoles(accounts, accountComparison, roleComparison);
}
```

Comment: I could possibly use this. It's a bit complicated for others to follow and introduces more code than I originally wanted, but +1 for an answer.

Comment: I think it will end up being less code. And each individual method is a lot shorter, which makes them easy to read. You don't pass in two nullable parameters and then figure out which one has a value, and you don't have duplication of most of the queries. There are also fewer conditional branches which makes the method easier to unit test. It's not so much about combining the queries. It's about keeping what they have in common and passing the rest as arguments. But in this case the arguments aren't values, they are conditions (functions.)

Comment: I actually like this answer. I'll try implementing it.